# State of the original redis master upon resurrection after sentinel failover

Tags: redis, jedis, redis-sentinel

Consider the following setup for a redis high-availability solution: 3 VMs each running an instance of redis server and an instance of sentinel to monitor the setup. `R1` (redis on `VM1`) is configured as a master, `R2` and `R3` as `slaveof R1`; `S1`... `S3` (sentinels) all monitor `R1` with quorum of 2. All of this is statically written into `redis.conf` and `redis-sentinel.conf` on the corresponding VMs.

Now consider `VM1` (carrying `R1` and `S1`) goes down. The sentinels elect e.g. `R2` as a new master and the client code, `jedis`, automatically adapts itself to the new state. So far so good.

What exactly happens when `VM1` is brought back up and `R1` and `S1` become available?

In particular:

- Will `R1` join the remaining `R2` and `R3` to form a 3-node setup again (e.g. because `S2` and `S3` keep monitoring it)?
- If yes, will `R1` get elected back to master or will remain a slave? Should I care at all?
- Will `S1` join `S2` and `S3` to form a 3-node setup again?
- Will `jedis` adapt automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentinel will convert the old master to a slave of the new master and nothing needs to change unless another failover happens in which case this is all repeated. The detail are at [the sentinel docs](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) which directly answer your question for sentinel.

Jedis won't need to care about the old master rejoining as a slave.